# Watir WebDriver Error Empty Body

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver, watir

I'm writing a watir script. It runs fine on OS X but when I run it on ubuntu, after the the first few watir commands, I get the following error:

`` empty body: "application/json" (500)
/home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:58:in `create_response'
/home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:65:in `request'
/home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
/home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:598:in `raw_execute'
/home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:576:in `execute'
/home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:183:in `switchToDefaultContent'
/home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/target_locator.rb:68:in `default_content'
/home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:180:in `assert_exists'
/home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/frame.rb:6:in `locate'
/home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:362:in `assert_exists'
/home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/frame.rb:30:in `assert_exists'
/home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:383:in `locate'
/home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:362:in `assert_exists'
/home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/select.rb:125:in `select_by'
/home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/select.rb:64:in `select'
/home/gabe/CTEC-Scraper/lib/tasks/scrape.rake:212:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/gabe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/rake:19:in `<main>' ``

NOTE: the 1 line form my file in the stack trace is

`frame.select_list(:name => 'SOME_ID').select('SOMETHING')`

and `frame` is `frame = @browser.frame(:id => 'SOME_FRAME')`

Again, this works in OS X. I am using Firefox as my browser. When I use Chrome, it gets passed this issue but breaks later on in a part of the site not compatible with Chrome (don't blame me, I didn't write it haha)

Comment: The response had an empty body. What's your question?

Comment: But why would this only be happening on Firefox on Linux? The page loads just fine, I only get the weird error in Watir.

Comment: Because they didn't do a good job of making that page compatible with fringe browsers I guess.